# Python Timeout script to kill thread active for more than X seconds

Tags: python, multithreading, timeout

I have been looking all over the place for a good timeout script that can kill a thread if it's been active for more than X seconds, but all the examples I've seen have flaws that don't always stop the thread. Using `thread.join(x)` ends up defeating the purpose of it being a thread.

The only decent example I have found is [Timeout on a function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-python-function-call) and that one is not without its flaws..

Anyone know of a better way to do this?

Comment: The Python folks made this hard on purpose because usually it's a bad idea to kill something that might be writing to shared memory. Could you use a process instead of a thread?

Comment: Well, in this case it's for a mod_wsgi script, so it's more of a termination thing. Once the script runs over the time limit, just kill the whole thread and exit, so potentially damaging shared memory isn't such a big problem.

Comment: Are you running in daemon mode or embedded mode?

Comment: it is a pain that there is no easy way to kill a thread, the thread could be a hanged up HTTP connection, due to DNS lookup etc.

Answer (score 2):

See my answer to [python: how to send packets in multi thread and then the thread kill itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605013/python-how-to-send-packets-in-multi-thread-and-then-the-thread-kill-itself/605865#605865) - there is a fragment with InterruptableThread class and example that kill another thread after timeout - exactly what you want.

There is also similar [Python recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/473878/) at activestate.

Answer (score 0):

I know this might not be what you want, but have you considered the signal approach?
[Timeout on a function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-python-function-call/494273#494273)
http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html#example

You can set an alarm signal at the beginning of the thread execution, and then stop the thread in the signal handler.

Comment: > This module doesn't play well with threads (but then, who does?)