# Place a timeout on calls to an unresponsive Flask route

Tags: python, flask

I currently have a route in a Flask app that pulls data from an external server and then pushes the results to the front end. The external server is occasionally slow or unresponsive. What's the best way to place a timeout on the route call, so that the front end doesn't hang if the external server is lagging? Or is there a more appropriate way to handle this situation in Flask (not Apache, nginx, etc)?

UPDATE: My goal is to timeout a route call, **not** keep an arbitrary long process alive like this SO question: [Time out issues with chrome and flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18127128/time-out-issues-with-chrome-and-flask). Options like websockets run background processes/threads until they finish; however, I want to stop a slow route call after some fixed amount of time has elapsed. Like [Timeout on a function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-python-function-call) and [Python Timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/811692/python-timeout) but within a Flask context. Celery's task decorator ([Concurrent asynchronous processes with Python, Flask and Celery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14588253/concurrent-asynchronous-processes-with-python-flask-and-celery)) seems like a great solution, but I don't want to require a large dependency to only use a small amount of its functionality.

I reopened this question here: [Place a timeout on calls to an unresponsive Flask route (updated)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18164393/place-a-timeout-on-calls-to-an-unresponsive-flask-route-updated).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Place a timeout on calls to an unresponsive Flask route (updated)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18164393/place-a-timeout-on-calls-to-an-unresponsive-flask-route-updated)