# How to kill main thread from sub thread in Jython

Tags: scripting, multithreading, jython

I have a script that creates a thread which after 60 seconds (this thread) needs to kill the main thread. I`m not sure what command I can use to kill the main thread. I'm using Jython 2.5.1 and Thread.interrupt_main doesn't work.

Here is the code:

```
import threading
def exitFunct():
    #exit code here
t = threading.Timer(60.0, exitFunct)
t.start()
for i in range(1, 3000):
    print i
```

Answer (score 0):

If the thread always terminates the main thread after 60 seconds, perhaps you'd be better using [Thread.Join()](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) in your main thread with a timeout?

And a link to the jython doc on [threading](http://www.jython.org/docs/library/threading.html)

Although it has occurred to me that this would block your main thread..

It also looks like the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605013/python-how-to-send-packets-in-multi-thread-and-then-the-thread-kill-itself/605865#605865) will help you.

If you post some example code that explains your problem and a deeper explanation of what you are trying to achieve with it, you'll get some better responses :)

Comment: Thanks, but yeah that can't happen, since the other thread is just timing the main one.