# Python threading passing statuses

Tags: python, multithreading

Basically what I'm trying to do is fetch a couple of websites using proxies and process the data. The problem is that the requests rarely fail in a convincing way, setting socket timeouts wasnt very helpful either because they often didn't work.

So what I did is:

```
q = Queue()
s = ['google.com','ebay.com',] # And so on
for item in s:
    q.put(item)


def worker():
        item = q.get()
        data = fetch(item) # This is the buggy part
        # Process the data, yadayada

for i in range(workers):
    t = InterruptableThread(target=worker)
    t.start()


# Somewhere else
if WorkerHasLivedLongerThanTimeout:
    worker.terminate()
```

[(InterruptableThread class)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605013/python--how-to-send-packets-in-multi-thread-and-then-the-thread-kill-itself)
The problem is that I only want to kill threads which are still stuck on the fetching part. Also, I want the item to return to the queue. Ie:

```
def worker():
        self.status = 0
        item = q.get()
        data = fetch(item) # This is the buggy part
        self.status = 1 # Don't kill me now, bro!
        # Process the data, yadayada

# Somewhere else
if WorkerHasLivedLongerThanTimeout and worker.status != 1:
    q.put(worker.item)
    worker.terminate()
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Have you ever looked at twisted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### *edit*: breaking news; see below · · · ······

I decided recently that I wanted to do something pretty similar, and what came out of it was the [pqueue_fetcher](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pqueue_fetcher) module.  It ended up being mainly a learning endeavour: I learned, among other things, that it's almost certainly better to use something like [twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com) than to try to kill Python threads with any sort of reliability.

That being said, there's code in that module that more or less answers your question.  It basically consists of a class whose objects can be set up to get locations from a priority queue and feed them into a `fetch` function that's supplied at object instantiation.  If the location's resources get successfully received before their thread is killed, they get forwarded on to the `results` queue; otherwise they're returned to the `locations` queue with a downgraded priority.  Success is determined by a passed-in function that defaults to `bool`.

Along the way I ended up creating the [terminable_thread](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/terminable_thread) module, which just packages the most mature variation I could find of the code you linked to as `InterruptableThread`.  It also adds a fix for 64-bit machines, which I needed in order to use that code on my ubuntu box.  `terminable_thread` is a dependency of `pqueue_fetcher`.

Probably the biggest stumbling block I hit is that raising an asynchronous exception as do `terminable_thread`, and the `InterruptableThread` you mentioned, can have some weird results.  In the test suite for `pqueue_fetcher`, the `fetch` function blocks by calling `time.sleep`.  I found that if a thread is `terminate()`d while so blocking, and the `sleep` call is the last (or not even the last) statement in a nested try block, execution will actually bounce to the `except` clause of the ***outer*** try block, *even if the inner one has an `except` matching the raised exception*.  I'm still sort of shaking my head in disbelief, but there's a test case in `pqueue_fetcher` that reenacts this.  I believe "leaky abstraction" is the correct term here.

I wrote a hacky workaround that just does some random thing (in this case getting a value from a generator) to break up the "atomicity" (not sure if that's actually what it is) of that part of the code.  This workaround can be overridden via the `fission` parameter to `pqueue_fetcher.Fetcher`.  It (i.e. the default one) seems to work, but certainly not in any way that I would consider particularly reliable or portable.

So my call after discovering this interesting piece of data was to heretofore avoid using this technique (i.e. calling `ctypes.pythonapi.PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc`) altogether.

In any case, this still won't work if you need to guarantee that any request whose entire data set has been received (and i.e. acknowledged to the server) gets forwarded on to `results`.  In order to be sure of that, you have to guarantee that the bit that does that last network transaction and the forwarding is guarded from being interrupted, without guarding the entire retrieval operation from being interrupted (since this would prevent timeouts from working..).  And in order to do that you need to basically rewrite the retrieval operation (i.e. the socket code) to be aware of whichever exception you're going to raise with `terminable_thread.Thread.raise_exc`.

I've yet to learn twisted, but being the Premier Python Asynchronous Networking Framework©™®, I expect it must have some elegant or at least workable way of dealing with such details.  I'm hoping it provides a parallel way to implement fetching from non-network sources (e.g. a local filestore, or a DB, or an etc.), since I'd like to build an app that can glean data from a variety of sources in a medium-agnostic way.

Anyhow, if you're still intent on trying to work out a way to manage the threads yourself, you can perhaps learn from my efforts.  Hope this helps.

#### · · · · ······ this just in:

I've realized that the tests that I thought had stabilized have actually not, and are giving inconsistent results.  This appears to be related to the issues mentioned above with exception handling and the use of the `fission` function.  I'm not really sure what's going on with it, and don't plan to investigate in the immediate future unless I end up having a need to actually do things this way.